# Getting points of intersection of axes

Tags: c#, revit-api

it is necessary to find the intersection points of the axes on the plan and insert families of instances into them

figured out how to create a new family, now it remains to understand how to find intersection points

Comment: Your question is unclear. "find the intersection points of the axes" - clarify that because this is simply (0, 0). What does "inserting families of instances into them" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some code would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection point is the zero point (0,0,0) in the family. By default, the 2 reference planes which names are "Left/Right" and "Front/Back" intersect each other at Zero point.

Unless you want to create the geometry of your family (which I assume it is) somewhere else, just move the reference planes and calculate the coordinate for the geometries accordingly. Keep in mind that when you place the instance of the Family in the project, the geometries will be transformed according to your modification.

Otherwise, just create geometries at Zero point. As for the reference plane, you can filter them by their name, which is might be different from the above since it depends on the language of Revit (which, again, I assume you don't use English).